# Get amount of CPT with a certain custom field value

Tags: wp-query

**What I try to achieve:**

Get the amount of CPT-posts with a certain condition.

**My fields**

CPT - 'usr_msg'
FIELD NAME - 'posted_user_id'

**My attemp**

```
add_shortcode('count_usr_msg','count_usr_msg');
function count_usr_msg($atts){
    $usr_id = $atts['usr_id'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type'              => array( 'usr_msg' ),
        'meta_query'             => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'posted_user_id',
                'value'   => $usr_id,
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        )
    );

    $usr_msg = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($usr_msg->have_posts()) {
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
        return $count_posts;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**The problem**

If I post a user_id that has 0 posts, it returns 0, but when I post a user_id 
that **has 1 or more it always returns 3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it returns wrong number, because you've coded it exactly in that way ;)

Your WP_Query is correct. So when there are no posts matching your conditions, then you get 0.

But when there are such posts, then... you ignore the query completely and return [`wp_count_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) as result... But...

This function returns an object, whose properties are the count of each post status of a post type. It does NOT count posts in given query - and TBH - in your case it couldn't do that (how should this function now what query to count posts of?)

So here's your code in correct form:

```
add_shortcode('count_usr_msg','count_usr_msg');
function count_usr_msg($atts){
    $usr_id = $atts['usr_id'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type'              => 'usr_msg',
        'meta_query'             => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'posted_user_id',
                'value'   => $usr_id,
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        )
    );

    $usr_msg = new WP_Query( $args );

    return $usr_msg->found_posts;
}
```

Instead of checking some conditions, we just use `found_posts`, which contains:

> The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters

and return it as a value.